# Updating count items with behaviorsubject cross side component communication

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a angular 8 application. and I have two components. one component where you can edit a item. And one component where you can see all the items. The items are divided in four categories. And for each category there is a counter that counts the items in each category. If I add a item the counter increase, so that works correct. But if I delete a item. The counter doest'n decrease.

So I have this service:

```
 _updateItemChanged = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  constructor() {}
}
```

and this is the

component where you can delete a item child component:

```
 remove() {
    this.dossierItemService.deleteDossierItem(this.data.dossierId, this.data.item.id)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.dialogRef.close(true);
        this.itemListService._updateItemChanged.next(this.data.item.title);
      }, (error) => {
        const processedErrors = this.errorProcessor.process(error);
        this.globalErrors = processedErrors.getGlobalValidationErrors();
    });
  }
```

and this is the parent component.html:

```
  <span i18n>Action steps</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.ActionStep) }}
```

and this is parent.ts code

```
 ngOnInit(): void {  
    this.itemlistService._updateItemChanged.subscribe(data => {
      this.dossierItems  = this.dossierItems.filter(d => d.title !== data);
    });
}
```

and the dossierItemsCountString function:

```
 dossierItemsCountBy(itemType: DossierItemTypeDto) {
    return this.typeSearchMatches[itemType.toString()] || { total: 0, matches: 0 };
  }

  dossierItemsCountString(itemType: DossierItemTypeDto) {  
    const count = this.dossierItemsCountBy(itemType);

    if (this.hasSearchQuery) {
      return `(${count.matches}/${count.total})`;
    } else {
      return `(${count.total})`;
    }
  }
```

So what I have to change so that in the parent component also the counter decrease if you remove a item.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you increasing the counter ? Where are you trying to decrease the counter ? I dont see that here. Do you mean `dossierItemsCountBy` ?

Comment: yes, that is where number of items are shown

Comment: Upload to stackblitz we may be more helpful

Comment: It is just after refresh page that the correct value will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion we found that the problem is in mixed pointers among components and the proper way to fix it is to manipulate the original array, instead of creating new one.

The solution:

```js
    this.itemlistService._updateItemRemoved.subscribe(data => {
      const index = this.dossierItems.findIndex(a => a.id === data.id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.dossierItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
```

Comment: But can I maybe write the methods into one method? But how?

Comment: do you mean dossierItemsCountBy and dossierItemsCountString?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. And how to make of this methods then a pipe?

Comment: I checked your question more carefully, I think you need to get rid of subscribe in the parent component with the filter. Simply listen on this.dossierItems, as I understand `remove` will remove an item from it so you would get a proper data. Then, instead of subscription in the component you can subscribe in the template as I show in the answer. could you update your question to show how you get `this.dossierItems` in the parent component?

Comment: sure. let's do that.